# Jquery library symfony collection doesn't work with <table> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony

When I add a element in my custom form theme, the incrementation of my collection doesn't works !

I use this library : https://github.com/ninsuo/symfony-collection

```
{% block PriceType_row %}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block PriceType_widget %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ form_widget(form.quantityFrom, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ form_widget(form.quantityTo, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ form_widget(form.bestUnitPrice, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ form_widget(form.getPaid, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ form_widget(form.vatRate, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endblock %}

{% block ProductType_widget %}
    {{ form_widget(form.prices) }}l
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Auto response]

I musted add an `elements_selector` to my collection javascript

```
$('.collection-prices').collection({
   elements_selector: '> tr',
});
```